# Sum up Specific Rows Based on Name in R and Create New Column

Tags: r

This is probably an easy question to answer, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

Assume I have the following dataframe:

```
    Name    Value
    Bob     100
    Bob     500
    Jim     50
    Rach    300
    Rach    300
    Rach    300
```

I need to create a new column that adds the value for each person.  The end result should look something like this:

```
    Name     Value      Sum
    Bob      100        600
    Bob      500        600
    Jim      50         50
    Rach     300        900
    Rach     300        900
    Rach     300        900
```

Thank you in advance for any help with this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Another simple solution is:

```
dat <- data.frame(Name = c('Bob', 'Bob', 'Jim', 'Rach', 'Rach', 'Rach'),
           Value = c(100, 500, 50, 300, 300, 300))
transform(dat, sum_name = ave(Value, Name, FUN = sum))
```

Comment: I got the error sum not meaningful for factors.  Do you know what is potentially wrong?

Comment: Make sure that the variable "Value" is numeric and not a factor and that it is the first argument of the ave function. Could it be that you specified "Value" as a second argument to ave?

Answer (score 1):

`plyr` is your friend:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, .(Name), transform, sum_name = sum(Value))
  Name Value sum_name
1  Bob   100      600
2  Bob   500      600
3  Jim    50       50
4 Rach   300      900
5 Rach   300      900
6 Rach   300      900
```

Assuming your data is in the `data.frame` `dat`. For other possible solutions take a look at the `data.table` package and the R base functions `aggregate`, `by`, `split`.